# Google web toolkit drawing SVG image onto Canvas widget

Tags: gwt, canvas, svg

Can't understand how to draw a SVG image onto Canvas widget in GWT. Tried to use canvg JS library, but i'm not familiar much with JS, with Raphael library - there is no any tutorial for SVG drawing. Anybody can help with a problem...? Thanx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick search I stumbled upon the [lib-gwt-svg](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-svg). Looks pretty complete, including some impressive [demos](http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt/lib-gwt-svg-edu-latest/lib-gwt-svg-edu.html).